# Drupal 8 - Solr 6.6.x Does not split fulltext field type values into mutliple words in spell

Tags: drupal, solr, full-text-search, drupal-8

I'm trying to setup a Solr 6.6.x schema.xml to work with a Drupal 8 (using Search API Solr), the main problem is indexed values are not split into multiple words (like : "Web developer" must be split in "Web" and "Developer" in spell) but it's not working, see below my schema.xml, any tips ?

[Screenshot of indexed examples in Solr UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4dk6.png)

Note: All my fields using this config :

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        -->
        <!-- Case insensitive stop word removal. -->
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="stopwords.txt"
        />
        <!--<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" />-->
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory"
                protected="protwords.txt"
                generateWordParts="1"
                generateNumberParts="1"
                catenateWords="0"
                catenateNumbers="0"
                catenateAll="0"
                splitOnCaseChange="1"
                preserveOriginal="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="100"/>
    </fieldType>
```

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/af00ed3052fc6e85140ed5ec9842e4bf

Comment: Welcome to SO! When possible, please add the relevant parts of code or configuration files to your question (in a *code block*). Use external links and images to supply *additional* information or context to supplement the code embedded in the question.

Comment: Sure, it's done :) !

Comment: Exactly what do you expect to happen? The value returned as the stored value for a field is _not_ affected by the processing chain, so it'll only show the verbatim value present when you indexed. Any processing will take place on the token level, splitting the text into separate tokens - and in your example, into `web` and `developer` as separate tokens.

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh, what I expect is to be able to type in my search "Hôtel" and have the results containing that word, such as "Accor Hôtel" (cf. photo). I would like to have this same behavior for all of my fields indexed in fulltext through the field type "text".

Comment: According to your field definition that should work as you expect. It doesn't? What is your query? What does the field show with your query and the indexed content under the "Analysis" page under the core on the admin page?

Comment: @MatsLindh do you have any tips to debug / log the Solr query from Drupal 8 using Views ?

Comment: No, but the Solr log can tell you that. You can change the log level under Solr's admin interface.

Comment: @MatsLindh i've this output :

 `/select params={q=*:*&defType=edismax&json.nl=flat&omitHeader=true&qf=&fl=ss_search_api_id,ss_search_api_language,score,hash&start=0&sort=score+desc,sort_title+asc&fq=(%2Bbs_status:"true"+%2Bss_type:"acteur")&fq=tm_ft_field_segment_entity_name:"hôtel"&fq=ss_search_api_language:"fr"&fq=index_id:"search"&rows=26&wt=json}`

This log can help you to understand ? Or you need another log ?

Comment: The previous query was not the original query from Search API Solr, i've modify it. The original one is this one : 

`/select params={q="hôtel"&defType=edismax&json.nl=flat&omitHeader=true&qf=tm_ft_field_segment_entity_name^1&fl=ss_search_api_id,ss_search_api_language,score,hash&start=0&sort=score+desc,sort_title+asc&fq=(%2Bbs_status:"true"+%2Bss_type:"acteur")&fq=ss_search_api_language:"fr"&fq=index_id:"search"&rows=26&wt=json}`

Comment: According to the last one you're only searching in the field `tm_ft_field_se‌​gment_entity_name`. I can't see that field in either of your documents, and since the `tm_*` field type is set to `stored`, there doesn't seem to be any value for that field.

Comment: Sure i've stored values for this field, take a look to this screenshot : https://s.nimbus.everhelper.me/share/1178362/1lqqfq1wiz4d4nx85xa3